# Can I prevent mismatch of a Nest.js route pattern and its param DTO via a static analyser (compile-time) or a non-specific autotest?

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, static-analysis

Consider the following route in a controller:

```
@Get('/:uuid')
findById(@Param() params: FindProjectParamsDto): Promise<Project> {
    return this.projectsService.findById(params);
}
```

Let's say that `FindProjectParamsDto` is defined like this:

```
export class FindProjectParamsDto extends PickType(ProjectDto, [
  'id',
] as const) {}
```

(or is not mapped, but just contains the `id` property). Let's also say that this property also has validators like `@IsNotEmpty()` or `@IsUUID()`.

You can easily spot a problem here: on a request, the extracted route param is `uuid`, while `params` is supposed to have `id`, hence `id` is empty. Such a request always fails as validators cause a response like:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "id must be a UUID",
    "id should not be empty"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I wonder if such a problem can be automatically prevented via a static code analyser. Obviously, TypeScript itself doesn't spot this as it doesn't care about the route string content. But may be there's already a standart solution to this for Nest.js?

May be a standart autotest that takes the DTO, populates values in the route using validators and/or examples (from `@ApiProperty`), passes it to the controller and checks that it doesn't invalidate it? (because `"/:uuid"` after substituting `":id"` with a valid value will still be `"/:uuid"` and hence the test will fail) Such a test will give false negative results, though: `"/:isGoodEnough"` with `isGood` in DTO will probably give something like `{ isGood: "trueEnough" }`, but this is obviously better than no validation (in the end, if `isGood` has `@IsBooleanString()`, `{ isGood: "trueEnough" }` won't pass).

Note: an autotest approach would be good enough if it can be applied to all routes at once; writing a specific autotest per route is way too much of an overhead.

PS: [this project](https://github.com/darraghoriordan/eslint-plugin-nestjs-typed/) does [a similar thing](https://github.com/darraghoriordan/eslint-plugin-nestjs-typed/blob/main/src/docs/rules/param-decorator-name-matches-route-param.md) using custom eslint rules, but only for non-DTO params. This may be an approach that can be use to handle this.

Comment: You can overload the signature (using a module augmentation) of the `Get` decorator factory such that, if it's passed the string `"/:uuid"`, it returns a decorator which will issue a compile error if applied to a method whose `params` are not of the required type.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sounds interesting. Any pointers to how to implement that?

Comment: I have not worked with Nest.js. does it use Legacy decorators or is it using the new standard of implementation?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Get('/:uuid')
findById(@Param() param: string): Promise<Project> {
return this.projectsService.findById(param.uuid);
}
```

You can do like this without dto.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about. DTO is used to provide validation for frontend, and more. I also provided an example with a single param for simplicity; it's not always the case.